# Calculate cash for hours, cash till 8 hours is 3$, after 8 it goes +5. Without "if"

Tags: math, lua

Like the title says, I want a mathematical function on Lua to calculate:
If a guy is working 8 hours, he gets paid 3$ per hour.
For any extra hour after 8 hours he gets paid 5$ per hour.

Only functions available are math.abs and math.floor. No if usage. It was a challenge for me and I failed, thought you could do it :)

Comment: Show your code, how does it fail?

Comment: It's not like it fails, I just couldn't get the correct math path. What I did was just cash = (hours*3) + math.abs(((hours-8)*2)), but nah will work only for 8+ hours.

Answer (score 1):

I used math.floor(hours/8.1) for all of the logic in this function. The way I did it was by multiplying the logic based numbers by this magic number, which will either evaluate to 0 (if the hours are less than 8.1) or 1 (if the hours are 8.1 or greater). Of course, this will fail if you use hours greater than 16, at which point it will start multiplying the overtime by 2, but if you're working a 16 hour day, you probably deserve double overtime anyways ;)

I used 8.1 instead of 8, that way the logic won't trigger on an 8 hour work day, only on a work day above 8 hours. The rest of the code is fairly straightforward (just try to look past my excessive use of parentheses)

```
function calculatePay(hours)
  return (3*hours)+((2*math.floor(hours/8.1))*((hours-8)*math.floor(hours/8.1)))
end

print(calculatePay(6)) -- 6*3 is 18 for regular pay, no overtime
print(calculatePay(8)) -- 8*3 is 24 for regular pay, no overtime
print(calculatePay(10)) -- 10*3 is 30 for regular pay, plus 4 (2*2) overtime 
print(calculatePay(12)) -- 12*3 is 36 for regular pay, plus 8 (4*2) overtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the variable for hours worked is `h`. Then, you have the following:

```
cash = h * 3 + (h <= 8 and 0 or (h - 8) * 2)
```

Comment: `condition and true_value or false_value` is an expression version of an if statement, which violates the spirit of the question.