# Calculating costs with change in price once the items go over a certain number

Tags: python

I need help finding a way to calculate the total cost of items when there is a change in the price once items go up to certain number in python 3.5.

For example,

First 6 items cost $8 each and after that, it costs $5 per item.

How can I achieve this without using an `if` statement and loop?

Comment: why dont you want to use an if statement, have you tried something?

Comment: I could achieve this using if statements but according to the lecture schedules if statements hasn't been learned yet. so i was wondering if there should be another way around like mathematically or something i am missing.

Comment: You may find this of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021866/calculate-cash-for-hours-cash-till-8-hours-is-3-after-8-it-goes-5-without/33024346#33024346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your variable is represented. How do you translate "First 6 items cost $8 each and after that, it costs $5 per item." into a `Python` object without using an `if` statement in the first place? My assumption is you don't. It's a complicated thing to do even with the `if` statement, I'm sure your lecture notes haven't touched on creating `functions` or `classes`, yet.

You'll probably end up creating a list by hand and maybe append elements to it later on manually, well not quite literally but yea, and if that's the case then you are in a bit of treat because `Python` has built in functions for calculating sums. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 27 2015, 12:06:50) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> costs = [6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
>>> total_cost = sum(costs)
>>> total_cost
76
>>>
```

Comment: Lecture notes touched functions and the exercise which contained my question showed up right after the lecture slide of function. I personally think that this exercise in this lecture slide could be incorrectly placed. The class starts next year so I can't even contact lecturer. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

A solution I drew up using while loops, I believe this runs as expected?

```
def total_cost(num_items):

    total = 0
    while num_items>6:
        total +=5
        num_items-=1
    while num_items>0:
        total +=8
        num_items-=1
    return total
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your help however Loop and if statements have not been learned yet according to the lecture slides I am studying for next year. so I was wondering if theres another way around it